# Create a dynamic datastructure from mysql in qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, dynamic-programming

My aim of the project is to display and perform some computations like comparing on the data from mysql database. The mysql database contains many tables and the first row in each table contains the names of the field such as id, name, PositionX, PositionY, BackgroundColor and their values in the lower row.

What I need is to create a dynamic datastructure in C++/ Qt with the name of the variables same as the name of the field. So that I can store the values based on the chosen table

So when I divide my problem into smaller steps
1. to identify the datatype based on the values.
2. to generate name of the variables same as the names in the row of the mysql table.
3. to create a dynamic struct

Example for a mysql table containing fields

ID PositionX PositionY BackgroundColor
0X32 233 256 0x3366

I can create a static datastructure

```
struct table
{
int ID,PositionX,PositionY,BackgroundColor;
}mytable;
```

Can I generate this struct dynamically?

PS:- (I have searched a bit  and I have encountered with some term called reflection but could not understand as I have moved to computer science recently (2 years), I do not know if I am in the right path).
Some Sample code should help me better rather than theories.

Comment: You can't do that. The best option is to use a qmap. This allows you to store the values in a structure with named keys for the values. You can assign the keys to be any values you like, such as the column names in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to understand the theory first, sorry, otherwise nothing of this will make any sense to you.

A C++ compiler performs name-erasure and lots of type-erasure. That means that once the compiler has compiled the code, the object storage is nameless and mostly typeless. Only the types of structures with virtual methods are known - but nothing is known about their members. A struct as a concept exists only while your code is being compiled. That concept ceases to exist as soon as the compiler is done.

Talking of a "dynamic" struct makes no sense in C++, because at runtime the object code knows nothing about what a "struct" is.

You can't reuse the compile-time struct concept at runtime, you must design your own instead. Since you're using Qt, you can represent a runtime-generated structure as a map from names to variants: `QMap<QString, QVariant>`. A `QVariant` can store any type known to Qt's metatype system, and you can let that system know about any custom types you might be using too.

Your `table` would look as follows, then:

```
using DStruct = QMap<QString, QVariant>;

// Create a prototype row
DStruct myTable;
myTable.insert("ID", QVariant{});
myTable.insert("PositionX", QVariant{});
myTable.insert("PositionY", QVariant{});
myTable.insert("BackgroundColor", QVariant{});

// Copy the prototype row and initialize it
DStruct myRow = myTable;
myRow["ID"] = 5;
myRow["PositionX"] = 12;
...
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. I agrée I am not that good with the theory. I got downvoted a lot for asking this question. Feels good now. To improve this answer can I do the following.  for(i =0 ;i<= column count ();i++) mytable.insert (stringatcolumn(i),Qvariant{}); further could you explain if this topic comes under reflection . Otherwise I'll un tag the reflection from it. Since I want to

Comment: Reflection is not directly related since you're not getting any information about the structure of the C++ code. So yes, you should remove that tag. Reflection is not currently possible for arbitrary C++ code without the use of additional tools. Qt's meta object compiler (moc) adds reflection information to classes with `Q_OBJECT` or `Q_GADGET` macro, but that information is limited to explicitly declared properties, signals, slots and invokable properties. It doesn't cover data members nor other methods.